# waitOn: setting a session value and then using to define a subscription

Tags: meteor

This is my route:

```
  this.route('friends', {
    path: '/friends',
    waitOn: function() {
     return Meteor.subscribe('friendsPlaylists', Session.get('friends'))
    }
  });
```

before this route I call a function which hits an api, and sets a session value:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(getFriends, {only: 'friends'})

var getFriends = function() {
  Meteor.call('getFriendsData', function(err, result) {
    Session.set('friends', result.data);
    Session.set('friendsLoaded', true);
  });
}
```

When the Meteor.subscribe is returned the session is not set due to asynchronous behavior.  How do I get the subscription to work, where it will wait for the session to be set?  Thanks ahead of time for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI onBeforeAction has an argument called pause which is a function that pauses the route execution so you could rewrite your code like this:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(getFriends, {only: 'friends'})

var getFriends = function(pause) {
  Meteor.call('getFriendsData', function(err, result) {
    Session.set('friends', result.data);
    Session.set('friendsLoaded', true);
  });
  if(!Session.get('friendsLoaded')){ pause(); }
  else{
     this.subscribe('friendsPlaylists', Session.get('friends')).wait();
  }
}
```

See: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#using-hooks

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to work.  I had to remove the .wait() tho.  because it would just hang forever.  Any idea why?